# Impersonation step missing in 2013 Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow2013

I noticed that Impersonation step missing in 2013 Workflow. Then how do we assign permissions for List items from workflow in 2013 workflows?

**Context** : SharePoint 2013 online and workflow 2013.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app step in 2013 is the equivalent of impersonation in 2010 workflows. If you aren't seeing this option available in SharePoint Designer, make sure you have the
Workflows can use app permissions site feature enabled.

Comment: But Eric till I am aware app step doesn't shows up any options like granting permissions( edit, create, etc) and it is mainly for providing access to modify any list's item. Please do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: App step is a bucket, anything you put it there is run under elevated privilege, including breaking and assigning permissions. If the actions are  not available anymore, you might need to use REST within the workflow to do it.

Comment: Hi  Eric, Any tutorial or Walk through if you could share with me ? How will I do it using Rest? ( I have done it before in 2010 where it was pretty straight forward).

Answer (score 2):

It is still available for you the 2010 template. I believe it was made redundant due to the problems it caused.

See links for reference
http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2011/04/15/impersonation-in-sharepoint-workflows-an-interesting-pitfall-aspx/

http://summit7systems.com/app-step-or-impersonation-step-in-sharepoint-designer-2013/

Comment: Susan I am looking forward for alternatives, I am well aware about the pitfalls with impersonation step. In your second link the alternative mentioned doesn't provides a generic solution (not appropriate for my requirement as well).